# SWT - OS agnostic way to get monospaced font

Tags: java, fonts, swt

Is there a way in SWT to get a monospaced font simply, that works across various operating systems?

For example. this works on Linux, but not Windows:

```
Font mono = new Font(parent.getDisplay(), "Mono", 10, SWT.NONE);
```

or do I need to have a method that tries loading varying fonts (Consolas, Terminal, Monaco, Mono) until one isn't null? Alternatively I could specify it in a properties file on startup.

I tried getting the system font from Display, but that wasn't monospaced.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the section on [Font Configuration Files](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/fontconfig.html) in the JDK documentation of [Internationalization Support](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/)-related APIs, the concept of **Logical Font**s is used to define certain platform-independent fonts which are mapped to physical fonts in the default font configuration files:

> The Java Platform defines five logical font names that every implementation must support: Serif, SansSerif, Monospaced, Dialog, and DialogInput. These logical font names are mapped to physical fonts in implementation dependent ways.

So in your case, I'd try

`Font mono = new Font(parent.getDisplay(), "Monospaced", 10, SWT.NONE);`

to get a handle to the physical monospaced font of the current platform your code is running on.

**Edit**: It seems that SWT doesn't know anything about logical fonts ([Bug 48055](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=48055) on eclipse.org describes this in detail). In this bug report a hackish workaround was suggested, where the name of the physical font may be retrieved from an AWT font...

Comment: This should also be available as java.awt.Font.MONOSPACED

Comment: It seems they provided a [SWTFontUtils](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=238603) class for this now.

Answer (score 39):

I spent a while bashing my head against this one until I realised that obviously eclipse must have access to a monospace font for use in its text fields, console etc. A little digging turned up:

```
Font terminalFont = JFaceResources.getFont(JFaceResources.TEXT_FONT);
```

Which works if all you're interested in is getting hold of some monospace font.

**Edit:** Or based on @ctron's comment:

```
Font font = JFaceResources.getTextFont();
```

**Edit:** Caveat (based on @Lii's comment): this will get you the configured Text Font, which can be overriden by the user and may not be a monospace font. However, it will be consistent with, e.g., the font used in the editor and console which is *probably* what you want.

Comment: Very nice! This is the only usable answer here

Comment: Or even a bit simpler:

Font font = JFaceResources.getTextFont ();

Comment: **This will not necessarily be a monospace font.** For example, in an Eclipse application it will be whatever font the user has configured in *Preferences > General > Colors and Fonts > Basic > Text Font*. It is the same font that is used by the basic text editor in Eclipse. Almost all users will have a monospace font of course, but you can't be sure.

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge, the AWT API does not expose underlying Font information. If you can get to it, I would expect it to be implementation dependent. Certainly, comparing the font mapping files in a couple of JRE lib directories, I can see that they are not defined in a consistent way.

You could load your own fonts, but that seems a little wasteful given you know the platform comes with what you need.

This is a hack that loads a JRE font:

```
private static Font loadMonospacedFont(Display display) {
    String jreHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
    File file = new File(jreHome, "/lib/fonts/LucidaTypewriterRegular.ttf");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(file.toString());
    }
    if (!display.loadFont(file.toString())) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(file.toString());
    }
    final Font font = new Font(display, "Lucida Sans Typewriter", 10,
            SWT.NORMAL);
    display.addListener(SWT.Dispose, new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            font.dispose();
        }
    });
    return font;
}
```

It works on IBM/Win32/JRE1.4, Sun/Win32/JRE1.6, Sun/Linux/JRE1.6, but is a pretty fragile approach. Depending on your needs for I18N, it could be trouble there too (I haven't checked).

Another hack would be to test the fonts available on the platform:

```
public class Monotest {

    private static boolean isMonospace(GC gc) {
        final String wide = "wgh8";
        final String narrow = "1l;.";
        assert wide.length() == narrow.length();
        return gc.textExtent(wide).x == gc.textExtent(narrow).x;
    }

    private static void testFont(Display display, Font font) {
        Image image = new Image(display, 100, 100);
        try {
            GC gc = new GC(image);
            try {
                gc.setFont(font);
                System.out.println(isMonospace(gc) + "\t"
                        + font.getFontData()[0].getName());
            } finally {
                gc.dispose();
            }
        } finally {
            image.dispose();
        }
    }

    private static void walkFonts(Display display) {
        final boolean scalable = true;
        for (FontData fontData : display.getFontList(null, scalable)) {
            Font font = new Font(display, fontData);
            try {
                testFont(display, font);
            } finally {
                font.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        try {
            walkFonts(display);
        } finally {
            display.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

This probably isn't a good approach as it may leave you exposed to locale issues. Besides, you don't know if the first monospaced font you come across isn't some windings icon set.

The best approach may just be to take your best guess based on a font/locale mapping whitelist and make sure that the users can easily reconfigure the UI to suit themselves via [FontDialog](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/FontDialog.html).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I believe the best option is as you say - specific a bland default like Courier that is available on all platforms, and allow the user to change this property with a font configuration dialog.

Comment: Is there any way to load 'Font' from Java resource or 'InputStream' rather than file path in SWT?

Comment: @parxier - not that I am aware of. This would be better as a new question.

Comment: Thanks, new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734106/how-to-load-font-from-inputstream-in-swt) created.

Answer (score 3):

For people who have the same problem, you can download any font ttf file, put it in the resource folder (in my case /font/****.ttf) and add this methode to your application. It's work 100 %.

```
public Font loadDigitalFont(int policeSize) {
    URL fontFile = YouClassName.class
            .getResource("/fonts/DS-DIGI.TTF");
    boolean isLoaded = Display.getCurrent().loadFont(fontFile.getPath());
    if (isLoaded) {
        FontData[] fd = Display.getCurrent().getFontList(null, true);
        FontData fontdata = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < fd.length; i++) {
            if (fd[i].getName().equals("DS-Digital")) {
                fontdata = fd[i];
                break;
            }}
        if (fontdata != null) {
            fontdata.setHeight(policeSize);
            fontdata.setStyle(SWT.BOLD);return new Font(getDisplay(), fontdata));}
    }return null;   }
```

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04 + Eclipse 3.7, but on Windows 7 + Eclipse 4.3 loadFont() returns false when its argument is a bundle URL rather than a file.

Comment: You should that the given relative path "/fonts/DS-DIGI.TTF" is in the resources directory, are you using maven ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want just a Monospaced font use "Courier" => `new Font(display, "Courier", 10, SWT.NORMAL)`