# Java Text in Text Editor isn't the same as the output

Tags: java

If I want something like this to appear:

```
+---------------------------------------+   
|                                       |
```

I have to put it it in notepad ++ as

```
System.out.println("+------------------------------------------------+");  
System.out.println("|                               |");
```

Is there a way to make the output appear as it does in the text editor? I read that it could be because of tabs/spaces being mixed, but I made sure to only use space-bar.

Comment: The spaces and hyphens in your sample code don't match. Is it a *typo*, or is that the actual code you're running?

Comment: You need to tell the editor your're using. (please notify @ me as I don't check for answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* the same text. It *isn't* the same font.

Use a [*monospaced* font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) in the text area (and Notepad++):

> A monospaced font, also called a fixed-pitch, fixed-width or non-proportional font, is a font whose letters and characters each occupy the same amount of horizontal space. This contrasts with variable-width fonts, where the letters differ in size from one another.

---

See [SWT - OS agnostic way to get monospaced font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221568/swt-os-agnostic-way-to-get-monospaced-font)

Comment: Courier seems to be monospaced http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samples_of_monospaced_typefaces and that is the font I am using.

Comment: @user3029479 It is. However, I believe the above is still accurate. Notepad++ won't write tabs - or other kinds of spaces - in strings on its own. Also, writing to `out` is not the same as writing to a JTextArea(?) which is .. an odd way to show the issue.

Comment: If Courier is a monospaced font, than why can't I just use that? I am just starting to learn programming so System.out.println is just what I was told to do.

Comment: Also I don't know where to add (this is the answer from your link). Just in the regular program? Font mono = new Font(parent.getDisplay(), "Monospaced", 10, SWT.NONE);

Comment: I messed around with the Fonts and themes and it fixed itself.

Answer (score 1):

if it really bothers you:

```
public String myFormat(int len, char ch, char margin) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append(margin);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(ch);
    }
    stringBuilder.append(margin);
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

System.out.println(myFormat(20, '-', '+'));
System.out.println(myFormat(20, ' ', '|'));
```

just an idea...