# Java SWT - StyledText how to show text using monospaced font

Tags: java, fonts, swt, styledtext, monospace

Is there any way to force StyledText widget to show text using monospaced font? It's not a problem of used font - I have tried 'Monospace', 'Courier', 'System', 'Fixedsys' and other monospaced fonts...
Normal Text widget shows text with monospaced font defaultly ('Fixedsys' font tested).

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a monospaced font with the methods shown in the answers to this question:

[SWT - OS agnostic way to get monospaced font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221568/swt-os-agnostic-way-to-get-monospaced-font)

Then simply call `StyledText#setFont(Font)`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    StyledText text = new StyledText(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI);
    text.setFont(JFaceResources.getFont(JFaceResources.TEXT_FONT));
    text.setText("|i|m|\n|m|i|");

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(200, 100);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]